# random terms in nested mixed effects

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme, nested-models

I have 300 subjects in 2 conditions and behavioral measures over 6 years. Each subject is measured twice (in each condition) at each time point.
I know would like to see if the slopes of condition one over time is different from the slope of condition 2 for the behavioral outcome. (using nlme in R)

would this be correct for the random terms:

```
    lme(behavior ~ age+condition*time, random=list(~time|subject, ~time|condition), na.action="na.omit", data=mydata)
```

Comment: No. You don't need `time|condition`.

Comment: but if I want to extract the slope of condition1 versus condition 2 (over time), how do I get that? when looking at the [model$coef$random$subject], I only see one slope per subject ?

Comment: That's the interaction effect condition*time.

Comment: So would the subject-specific slope of condition 1 (ref) be:
age (centered) + fixed estimate of time + random estimate of time for each subject
//
and the subject-specific slope of condition 2:
  age (centered) + fixed estimate of time +fixed estimate of condition+ fixed estimate of the interaction + random estimate of time for each subject

Comment: Why do you need any of that? You want to look at the difference in time slopes between conditions. That's given by the condition*time coefficient. You will see it directly in the model output.

Comment: I want to extract those numbers to correlate them with another variable, to see if a difference predicts worse performance on cognition (similar to having BLUPs)
Also, not sure, but isn't it normal to expect that condition 1 and 2 start at different points (they are correlated, but still..)? So that is why I entered them in the random terms, not sure I understand why I should not do it? Any information on that is appreciated.